# Not able to connect to Google cloud Paas instance from Google cloud VM. Both are in different region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am not able to connect the GC paas instance from GC VM. Both are in different regions. They both are in the same VPC but in different regions. VPC network peering is not possible as they both are in same VPC. Is there any option to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are your PaaS services that you use? And in which region? Can you share more about  your configuration?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere its postgres instance in europe

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere to give more info, we have region-specific subnets. pass instance and GC VM are not in the same subnet. there is no communication between those both subnets

Comment: Subnet are regional, VPC are global. You don't need to peer your subnet inter-region (as you can do with AWS). Be sure that the firewall are open. Anyway, what is your PaaS instance, what is it? which service?

Comment: Our instance is of PostgreSQL.

Comment: What about your firewall rules?